# PFLoginViewController not showing Facebook login button with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift, parse-platform

Here is my Swift code:

```
        let loginViewController = PFLogInViewController()
        loginViewController.delegate = self;
        loginViewController.signUpController.delegate = self;
        loginViewController.fields = PFLogInFields.Facebook
        self.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: animated, completion: nil)
```

I have tried everything possible, but don't know why it is not showing the Facebook login button. It just shows the default fields.

Answer (score 2):

Check again:

1. if you have in appdelegate [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook]
2. you have to add, also `PFLogInFieldsDismissButton`
3. you must also set the facebookPermissions property to the a list of the permissions we want to be granted by the user

Example for ObjC

```
if (![PFUser currentUser]) {        
        // Customize the Log In View Controller
        PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
        [logInViewController setDelegate:self];
        [logInViewController setFacebookPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"friends_about_me", nil]];
        [logInViewController setFields: PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsDismissButton];

        // Present Log In View Controller
        [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TonyMkenu. I have added the [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook] still not working. Also added the PFLogInFieldsDismissButton, like this loginViewController.fields = PFLogInFields.Facebook | PFLogInFields.DismissButton Still not working.

You mentioned in your answer "initializeWithConsumerKey" What is this?

Comment: sorry ... initializeWithConsumerKey it's for Twitter

Answer (score 2):

Try **not setting** the ***signUpController delegate***, thus remove the line:

```
loginViewController.signUpController.delegate = self
```

EDIT:  It seems to be an error in the Parse SDK.

I got around it by setting the **signUpController.delegate** only ***áfter presenting*** the loginViewController.

(Thus present the PFLoginViewController, with the Facebook & Twitter fields included, and only thereafter set the signUpViewController's delegate).

Answer (score 1):

Also, I noticed that in the present ParseUI version (1.1.5), the Facebook login button is not compatible with emailAsUsername.

Therefore, if you have the following line:

```
loginViewController.emailAsUsername = true
```

the Facebook button will not appear.

The following code successfully created a login screen with Facebook button ; if it can be of help to someone:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // MARK: - ParseUI logIn / signUp screen
        let loginViewController = PFLogInViewController()
        loginViewController.delegate = self

        loginViewController.fields = (
            PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword |
            PFLogInFields.LogInButton |
            PFLogInFields.SignUpButton |
            PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten |
//            PFLogInFields.DismissButton |
            PFLogInFields.Facebook
        )

        loginViewController.facebookPermissions = ["public_profile"]

        self.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
}
```

EDIT: the Parse team just emailed me that it's definitely a bug that they are investigating. I hope they fix it soon!